# What is the best approach for using std::ranges/std::views with std::expected in C++23?

Tags: c++, c++20, c++23

Let me describe a scenario, first we have a function which returns us some sort of data which we can't be sure about the validity of, i.e.

```
auto random_predicate() -> bool
{
    int v = uniform_dist(e1); // uniform distribution 1 to 100
    return (v % 5);
}
```

where `uniform_dist()` is an appropriately seeded uniform distribution, and we have an `enum class` which we shall use for error handling, i.e.

```
enum class Error
{
    ValueError
};
```

Then we perform some sort of views-based processing which uses `random_predicate()` from within an operation, as follows:

```
std::vector<int> vs{1,2,3,4,5};

auto result = vs
   | views::filter([](int i){ return i % 2; })
   | views::transform([](int i) -> std::expected<int, Error> {
      auto v = random_predicate();
      if (v) return std::unexpected<Error>(Error::ValueError);
      else return i * i; 
   });
```

So, by the end of this operation, we can assert

```
static_assert(
    std::is_same_v<
        std::decay_t<std::ranges::range_value_t<result>>, 
        std::expected<int, Error>
    >
)
```

will in fact be true.

The question is, then what? We know have a view of `std::expected` values which we need to resolve to either: an error type which propagates up the call stack, or a view of the success type (i.e. a view of `int` in the above example (with all elements not a multiple of 5!))

---

## My solution

My solution is to simply check if each element is in error and then if there are no errors transform the result to the desired view, so something like

```
template<typename T>
static auto has_error(const std::expected<T, Error>& e){ return !e.has_value(); };

auto f(const std::vector<int>& vs)
{    
    auto c = vs
        | views::filter([](int i){ return i % 2; })
        | views::transform([](int i) -> std::expected<int, Error> {
            auto v = random_predicate();
            if (v) return std::unexpected<Error>(Error::ValueError);
            else return i * i; 
        });

    if (auto v = ranges::find_if(c, has_error<int>); v != c.end()) 
    {
        return (*v).error();
    }
    else 
    {
        return c | views::transform([](auto&& e){ return e.value(); });
    }
}
```

But then we run into the problem that the function cannot deduce the return type to be `std::expected<T, Error>` where `T` is the type of a container with elements of type (in the case of the above example) `int`. And well, I dont even know what to write for `T` here, so my question is how should this be implemented?

godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/Wfjr8o3qM

---

Alternatively, I'm interested in hearing how others may approach this problem in a better way all together?

Thanks

Edit: I suppose, you dont really want to return a view of some elements as it may lead to a dangling view? In that case, is it best to just use `ranges::to<T>()` when returning from a function?

Comment: Definitely not an easy question. If performance is not an issue and you can use external libraries, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67716780/is-it-possible-advisable-to-return-a-range suggests to use any_view from ranges-v3. Regarding your edit, I think that as long as your original data is valid in the scope of where you use the views it should be fine (like with the code on SO, not with the one in the Godbolt)

Comment: Thank you, yes, I updated the question to move the vector out of the function for that very reason, but forgot to update the godbolt! Thank you for the link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another option to still be able to return the range:

```cpp
auto f(const std::vector<int> &vs) {
    auto c = vs
             | views::filter([](int i) { return i % 2; })
             | views::transform([](int i) -> std::expected<int, Error> {
        auto v = random_predicate();
        if (v) return std::unexpected<Error>(Error::ValueError);
        else return i * i;
    });

    auto values = c | views::transform([](auto &&e) { return e.value(); });

    using success_t = decltype(values);
    using ret_t = std::expected<success_t, Error>;

    if (auto v = ranges::find_if(c, has_error<int>); v != c.end()) {
        return ret_t(std::unexpected<Error>((*v).error()));
    } else {
        return ret_t(values);
    }
}
```

It uses the fact that values as it is a view is computed lazily. So if it is not returned, values will never be computed, and we can use it to determine the return type. Next step is to ensure all returns are wrapped into the `ret_t` type so that auto can guess correctly.

Note: both in this answer and your original question, this only works in the original range can be iterated on multiple time (can't remember the name of this concept sorry)

Comment: "*both in this answer and your original question, this only works in the original range can be iterated on multiple time*" Namely, `ranges::forward_range`.

Answer (score 3):

The first thing to note is that since the lambda passed into `views::transform` uses `random_predicate()` internally, it will produce different results each time it is invoked, which violates *equality-preserving*, so the lambda does not meet the `regular_invocable` required by `transform_view`, you've got a UB.

---

As [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73776367/11638718) illustrates, suppose you have a range of `std::expected<int, E>`, you may want to collect them into `std::expected<std::vector<int>, E>`, which is quite useful (That's why `ranges::to` does not constrain the return type to be a `range` in the end).

Although it is [still not possible](https://github.com/microsoft/STL/pull/3319#issuecomment-1374852395) to get the "correct" behavior described by the answer via `ranges::to<expected>` for the current standard, it is not difficult to implement that:

```
template<ranges::input_range R>
  requires is_expected<ranges::range_value_t<R>>
auto to_expected(R&& r) {
  using expected_type = ranges::range_value_t<R>;
  using value_type = expected_type::value_type;
  using error_type = expected_type::error_type;
  using return_type = std::expected<std::vector<value_type>, error_type>;

  std::vector<value_type> v;
  for (auto it = r.begin(); it != r.end(); ++it) {
    if ((*it).has_value())
      v.push_back((*it).value());
    else
      return return_type(std::unexpect, (*it).error());
  }
  return return_type(std::move(v));
}
```

Then in your example, you can pass the range of `std::expected<int, E>` into this function to get a `std::expected<std::vector<int>, E>`

```
auto f() {
  std::vector<int> vs{1,2,3,4,5};
  auto c = vs | views::filter([](int i){ return i % 2; });

  // make a range of std::expected
  std::vector<std::expected<int, Error>> r;
  for (int i : c) {
    if (random_predicate())
      r.emplace_back(std::unexpected<Error>(Error::ValueError));
    else
      r.emplace_back(i * i);
  }

  return to_expected(r);
}
```

which ensures we only traverse the original range once, making it work even if it is an `input_range`.

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/x3T4jE68G)

Comment: Very nice, thank you. I did not know that it was undefined behaviour, but this is a very useful bit of code!

Comment: That's UB, which is likely to produce unexpected results, eg. https://godbolt.org/z/j1KqxYncP